# How to search and replace text in Word document using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have one .docx file and `Dictionary<string,string>` . I need to go through the document, and replace the text eqaul to `Dictionary.Key` to its according value in `Dictionary`. It will be on server, because of that I don't want to use `Microsoft.Office.Interopt` library which generates COM objects. For the solution i prefered `OpenXML`, but on web for me there is no working solution for it. I found  [this solution of Eric White](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/05/12/148357.aspx) . It didn't work for me. Exactly to say, I run method `SearchAndReplace` but there is no changes in document. I went through the methods, and found the problem was in method `PutXmlInDocument` method, which saves `XmlDocument` to given `OpenXmlPart` by getting stream of it.  Is there any other solutions with using `OpenXML` or what to do save `XmlDocument` to `OpenXmlPart`?

It is that method which saving was unsuccessful :

```
public static void PutXmlDocument(OpenXmlPart part, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        using (Stream partStream = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (XmlWriter partXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(partStream))
            xmlDoc.Save(partXmlWriter);

    }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87711/Manipulate-Docx-with-C-without-Microsoft-Word-inst

Comment: Is it in a paragraph? Is it in a table? Is it in the header? Is it in the footer? How many values of these are in the docx? If there are more than one, do you want to replace all of them or just the first one? We need a lot more info.

Comment: I have no info about that. I have a list of "search values" and a list of "new values" . I need to search "search value" and change it to "new value" . It can be each of you wrote above.

Comment: @Javidan, how do you not know? Your answer to this question makes my answer vary by up to 100-200 lines. Can you not make any assumptions?

Comment: I can only say that, it cannot be in header and in footer.

Comment: As in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, I know there a method of `Replace` . I need something like it

Comment: I found this [solution of Eric White](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/05/12/148357.aspx) ,but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you guys are able to, could you help out with this? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted to blogger, and asked about this situation. At last I reach to this solution. If replacing is 1 per `WordprocessingDocument` then Eric White's solution works great. But if it is more than 1, then after compliting all replacements the below method must be called before doing something with `WordprocessingDocument`.

```
WordprocessingDocument.Package.Close();
```