# Using OpenXML SDK to replace text on a docx file with a line break (newline)

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I am trying to use C# to replace a specific string of text on an **entire** DOCX file with a line break (newline).

**The string of text that I am searching for could be in a paragraph or in a table in the file.**

I am currently using the code below to replace text.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("yourdoc.docx", true))
{
  var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

  foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
  {
    if (text.Text.Contains("##Text1##"))
    {
      text.Text = text.Text.Replace("##Text1##", Environment.NewLine);
    }
  }
}
```

**ISSUE:** When I run this code, the output DOCX file has the text replaced with a space (i.e. " ") instead of a line break.

How can I change this code to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml). Check the example on this link. You just have to append a Break

Paragraphs, smart tags, hyperlinks are all inside [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.run(v=office.15).aspx). So maybe you could try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316873/replace-text-in-word-document-using-open-xml).
To change the text inside a table, you will have to use this [approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850835(v=office.15).aspx). Again the text is always inside a Run.

If you are saying that the replace is only replacing for an empty string, i would try this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"yourpath\testdocument.docx", true))
        {
            var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        if (text.Text.Contains("text-to-replace"))
                        {
                            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("text-to-replace", "");
            run.AppendChild(new Break());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Using `run.AppendChild(new Break());` will probably create a new line. But how can I have that put into the document only where it is supposed to replace the text?

Comment: The `Text.Replace()` function only accepts two strings I believe

Comment: This only replaces single-run text. Text may be split up in multiple runs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a line break, try making two paragraphs, one before the "text to be replaced" and one after. Doing that will automatically add a line break between two paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

text.Parent.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break());

Comment: Hi Arun, welcome to SO. Can you please edit this answer to explain why this code fixes the problem, and how it works? Code only answers are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Open a WordprocessingDocument for editing using the filepath.
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
{
 // Assign a reference to the existing document body.
 Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

 //itenerate throught text
 foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
 {
   text.Parent.Append(new Text("Text:"));
   text.Parent.Append(new Break());
   text.Parent.Append(new Text("Text"));
 }
}
```

This will return:

Text:
Text: